# log4j DailyRollingFileAppender does not create file with date pattern

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Using org.apache.log4j in a Java 8 application, I want a new log file to be created every hour with name e.g.: "mylog.log.2014-09-24-18". 
I read I need to use DailyRollingFileAppender, but when I start the application the log file is named "mylog.log".

This is the content of my log4j.properties file:

```
# Set root logger level and its appenders
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.File=mylog.log
log4j.appender.file.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Can you please let me know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I set the `DatePattern` to `log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm`, when I logged first time, the log wrote into mylog.log, and one minute later, log wrote into `mylog.log.2014-09-24-10-42`. So i think the first time your log will write into mylog.log, and an hour later, the system will generate a file named `'mylog.log.2014-09-24-10'`.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I wrongly assumed that the file is created immediately with the date pattern.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, what you are looking for is, you want the active log file already create with date/time in the file name, and once rolling is required, it will simply log to a new file with latest date/time in file name.

If my understanding is correct I wonder if log4j 1.x can do what you are looking for.

Log4J is simply writing to `mylog.log` and upon rolling, it move the original `mylog.log` to `mylog.log.yyyy-mm-dd` and then create a new `mylog.log` again.

If you are using SLF4J, and if there is no special reason for you to stick to Log4J as backend, `Logback` actually is providing what you are looking for:

http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#TimeBasedRollingPolicy

Omit the `file` property in `RollingFileAppender`, and setup the file pattern in the `TimeBasedRollingPolicy`.  The way log files are created will be what you are expecting.